# Spring DefaultMessageListenerContainer

Tags: spring, jms

Here's my Spring JMS configuration

```
<jms:listener-container connection-factory="connectionFactory" destination-resolver="jndiDestinationResolver">
<jms:listener id = "listener1" destination ="${queue1}" ref="myListener1" />
<jms:listener id = "listener2" destination ="${queue2}" ref="myListener2" />
<jms:listener id = "listener3" destination ="${queue3}" ref="myListener3" />
</jms:listener-container>
```

I am building some custom GUI to start or stop the JMS listeners.
In DefaultMessageListenerContainer, we have methods only to start and stop.

Is there any way to find out whether the listener is already stopped or not?

I have to provide the start button only if it's already stopped.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method called isRunning(). That helps.